# How do I programmatically get sub terms in a reused term?

Tags: development, managed-metadata, term-store, term-set

Lets say I have two Term Sets named: A & B. In Term Set **A** I have a term **X** that i want to reuse in Term Set **B**. Under **X** I have some "Child-Terms".

How do i programmatically get the "Child-Terms" of **X**?

Get Term should do the job if there where two instances of different terms that had the same name. (The job of getting the two instances of **X** which I could then get the child terms from)

```
TermCollection tc = session.GetTerms(term.Name, true);
```

How should I tackle this problem?

Development on SharePoint 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the sspId from the field on the item I was working on I was able to get the child terms from a Reused Term.

```
TermStore termStore = session.TermStores.FirstOrDefault(ts => ts.Id == taxField.SspId);                                                        
TermSet termSet = termStore.GetTermSet(taxField.TermSetId);                                                      
Term reusedTerm = termSet.Terms.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Labels.Any(l => l.Value == originalTerm.Name));
reusedTerm.terms <<<<----- here's X
```